# QGIS Handle Bad Layers Window Size

Tags: qgis, layers

I'm using QGIS 2.18.9.
Using the Handle Bad Layers Window, I find that I can't change the window size or the size of the individual columns.  Sometimes I have a long path and/or file name and see only the first few characters in the relevant column.  I might have several layer files with the same first few characters and hence don't know what file to browse for.
Is there some way of enlarging the window and columns?
I have just discovered that if I double-click on the visible text in the Datasource column, the complete filename is displayed.

Comment: What about double-clicking on the shared side of the header for the field of interest and the next one?

Comment: I can do that, but I'd feel more comfortable if I could change the extents of the window to achieve a similar result.

Comment: You can resize the window by dragging the outermost border of the window, at least in the Windows build of 2.18.9.  Unlike most other windows, the mouse cursor doesn't change when you move it to the border.  You can also right click on the top bar and select "size", but at least when I've tried it, you can only adjust the height of the window.